# $1 - \sqrt{5}$ $\in$ $\mathbf{R}$?

Tags: equation-solving

Why is there a difference in the output of the following codes?

First:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

a = {0, -m};
b = {-(Sqrt[-2 + m^2]/Sqrt[m]), -m - (-2 + m^2)^2/m};
c = {-1, 1} b;
d = 1024 m (-2 + m^2)^3;
o = {0, 0};

Reduce[{d > 0, EuclideanDistance[a, o] == EuclideanDistance[b, c]}, m]
```

> ```
> m == 2 || m == 1 - Sqrt[5] || m == 1 + Sqrt[5]
> ```

And then with `Reals`:

```
Reduce[{d > 0, EuclideanDistance[a, o] == EuclideanDistance[b, c]}, m, Reals]
```

> ```
> m == 2 || m == 1 + Sqrt[5]
> ```

Comment: By the way `ClearAll;` is not a command; try: ``ClearAll["Global`*"]``.  The **All** in `ClearAll` does not mean all Symbols, but rather all Symbol properties, including Attributes, Default, etc.

Comment: My guess would be that, because some subexpression (in particular `Sqrt[-2 + m^2]` in `EuclideanDistance[b, c]`) becomes imaginary for the value `m == 1 - Sqrt[5]`, `Reduce` throws that solution away, even though all variables are real. But because I don't know the internals of `Reduce`, it's a pure guess ...

Comment: I think @TeakeNutma is right.  Change `b = {Sqrt[(-2 + m^2)/m],..}` and `1 - Sqrt[5]` shows up again as a `Real` solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
Reduce[d > 0 && EuclideanDistance[a, o] == EuclideanDistance[b, c] && 
  m \[Element] Reals, m, Complexes]
```

> ```
> m == 2 || m == 1 - Sqrt[5] || m == 1 + Sqrt[5]
> ```

As from the documentation page of `Reduce` we have

[image]

It seems to me Teake Nutma was right.

Comment: Well, I wasn't right about this being some undocumented internal behaviour of `Reduce`. Thankfully some people still know how to read docs :).